# Como capturar o valor do atributo src de um iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Tenho que capturar o valor de um atributo de um iframe na `pagina.html`, a partir da página pai `pai.html`. Já tentei de tudo mas não obtive sucesso.

**pai.html**:

```
<iframe id="meuframe" src="//www.site.com.br/fotos/pagina.html"></iframe>
<br></br>

<button onclick="iframejs();">icone</button>

<script>
    function iframejs() {
        var iframe = window.parent.meuframe.document.getElementById( "video_html" );
        alert( iframe.getAttribute( "src" ) );
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**pagina.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    ...

    <video id="video_html5" src="video.mp4" class="video-gs"></video> 

    ...
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `pai.html` está com a `iframe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com jQuery, você pode usar o método [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
$('#meuframe').contents().find('#video_html').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

acabei usando este em javascript

```
    var video = window.parent.meuframe.document.getElementById("video_html").src;
```

mas não fuciona no Chrome ,

com o jquery também não funcionou !

```
   $('#meuframe').contents().find('#video_html').attr('src');
```

mas no IE não tive problema